# PHP Image Zoom - Exponential scale

Tags: php, image, math, zooming, exponential

Iam trying to calculate a zoom Effect beetween 12 Images. Every Image is 100% larger then the one before. Its geting near to perfect, but there is only a issue at the transition beetween the images. It isn't fluid zoom beetween each image. 
Please see the video: http://youtu.be/dUBbDjewpO0

I think the Exponential expression pow() isnt coorect for some reason.
Here is the PHP script, but i cant find the issue:

```
 <?php
    $imageFiles=array(
     '1.jpg',
     '2.jpg',
     '3.jpg',        
     '4.jpg');
 $targetFrameRate=$targetDuration='18';
 $imageCount = count($imageFiles);
 $totalFrames        = ($targetFrameRate*$targetDuration);
 $sourceIndex  = 0;
 $firstIndex   = 1;
 $lastIndex    = $totalFrames; //==total frames
 $currentScale = 1;//image scaling for first scale 
 $deltaScale   = ((($imageCount-1)*($scaleFactor-$currentScale))/$totalFrames);

  for ($i=$firstIndex; $i<=$lastIndex; $i++) {

// prepare filename

$filename = createImageFilename($i, $imageType);

// determine source..
if ($i == $firstIndex) {
    $newSourceIndex = 0;
}
else if ($i == $lastIndex) {
    $newSourceIndex = ($imageCount-1);
}
else {
     $newSourceIndex = intval(($i*($imageCount-1))/$totalFrames);

}
// create frame..
if ($newSourceIndex != $sourceIndex) {
    $sourceIndex  = $newSourceIndex;
    $currentScale = pow($scaleFactor, $sourceIndex);
    $nextScale    = pow($scaleFactor, ($sourceIndex+1));
    $deltaScale   = ((($imageCount-1)*($nextScale-$currentScale))/$totalFrames);

    copyImage($imageFiles[$sourceIndex], 
              sprintf('%s/%s', $outputDir, $filename), 
              $imageWidth, 
              $imageHeight, 
              $imageType);
}
else {
    createImage($imageFiles[$sourceIndex], 
                sprintf('%s/%s', $outputDir, $filename), 
                ($currentScale/pow($scaleFactor, $sourceIndex)),
                $imageWidth, 
                $imageHeight, 
                $imageType);
}

//DEBUG: buffer some values for optional debug-output
if (isDebugOutputEnabled()) {
    $debug_idx[$i] = $filename;
    $debug_inf[$i] = sprintf('sourceIndex=%d , scale=%01.2f<br />', $sourceIndex, $currentScale);
}
// advance..
$currentScale += $deltaScale;
 }


 ?>
```

rendering is well

```
  shell_exec('ffmpeg -f image2 -i /var/www/htdocs/image2/i%d.jpg -s 1280x720 -movflags faststart -b:v 5500k -r 18 output.flv');
```

Comment: video is offline ...

Comment: its a zoom effect https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76nR2oAlIWI&t=3s
i solved all with After Effects already

Comment: you can check this fiddle: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/VMyeqZ (it's not mine but i could imagine it's what you were looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you are adding a delta to your scale instead of multiplying it by a constant amount each frame:

```
$currentScale += $deltaScale;
```

An exponential zoom means you increase the zoom by a constant *factor* (not difference) for a given constant amount of time, so you need to change that line to:

```
$currentScale *= $deltaScale;
```

and also calculate `$deltaScale` differently:

```
$deltaScale = pow($nextScale / $currentScale, ($imageCount-1) / $totalFrames);
```

This will compute a fractional power of the scale difference between the images, so that when you multiply it with the `$currentScale` value `$totalFrames / ($imageCount-1)` times (the number of frame you render between the current scale and next scale), the result will be an increase by a factor of `$nextScale / $currentScale`.

Simplification:

Because the zoom is at a constant rate for the whole animation, `$deltaScale` is constant the whole time, so you can compute it outside the loop like this:

```
$deltaScale = pow($scaleFactor, ($imageCount-1) / $totalFrames);
```

Comment: Can you contact me, do you work for Money? I need a bezier function implementation in this code below^ (Smooth in and Smooth out)